# Why removing jcenter() repository fails my Android Application build for sqlite-android:3.36.0

Tags: android, gradle, jcenter

I've updated my Android Application gradle to use `AGP 7.0`

my gradle `repositories` resembles this

```
repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
```

This shows that `JCenter Maven repository is no longer receiving updates: newer library versions may be available elsewhere`

When I remove `jcenter()` my build fails with this error

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDevelopmentDebugNativeLibs'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:developmentDebugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not find io.requery:sqlite-android:3.34.1.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/io/requery/sqlite-android/3.34.1/sqlite-android-3.34.1.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/io/requery/sqlite-android/3.34.1/sqlite-android-3.34.1.pom
     Required by:
         project :app > project :background:worker > project :background:database
```

As my application employs  `api 'io.requery:sqlite-android:3.34.1'`

The `requery` GitHub README.md file states I need to use the following gradle entry

```
allprojects {
        repositories {
            ...
            maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
        }
    }
```

However adding the above does not fix my gradle build error

Where am I going wrong?

I updated to `sqlite-android:3.36.0` and stil get...

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDevelopmentDebugNativeLibs'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:developmentDebugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not find io.requery:sqlite-android:3.36.0.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/io/requery/sqlite-android/3.36.0/sqlite-android-3.36.0.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/io/requery/sqlite-android/3.36.0/sqlite-android-3.36.0.pom
       - https://jitpack.io/io/requery/sqlite-android/3.36.0/sqlite-android-3.36.0.pom
     Required by:
             project :app > project :background:worker > project :background:database
```

I have identified the issue

When I have this entry my build works:-

```
implementation 'com.github.requery:sqlite-android:3.36.0'
```

When I have this entry my build fails:-

```
api 'com.github.requery:sqlite-android:3.36.0'
```

Comment: I don't see version 3.34.1 in the release list: https://github.com/requery/sqlite-android/releases so perhaps it was a temporary/deprecated version.